# Lens trying to connect with gcp auth plugin instead of gcloud

Tags: gcloud, deprecation-warning

The Lens version is: 2022.10.311317

The error is the following:

```
W1107 09:36:53.839057 18484 gcp.go:120] WARNING: the gcp auth plugin is deprecated in v1.22+, unavailable in v1.25+; use gcloud instead.
To learn more, consult https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
```

Google Cloud SDK:

```
gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 408.0.1
bq 2.0.81
core 2022.11.01
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin 0.4.0
gsutil 5.16
```

and I have the gke gcloud auth plugin installed, as suggested by the link in the error.

```
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin.exe --version
Kubernetes v1.25.2-alpha+ae91c1fc0c443c464a4c878ffa2a4544483c6d1f
```

Update and followed the guides.

Comment: What is "Lens"?

Comment: Do you have the environment variable set `USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True`? This ensures that `kubectl` uses `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`

Comment: @DazWilkin yes I did, but doesn't work anyway.